# Dual Boot Windows/Debian no longer boot Windows. How to access cmd prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have a dual boot notebook that had Win10 and Debian installed, after using windows yesterday the debian/GRUB would no longer boot. (BTW that is still a problem, if you can help see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573218/400466))

While trying to fix the Debian I decided to run this command [**in WINDOWS**]

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi
```

After that my note doesn't boot anything, nor Windows or Debian. According to [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) I need to run the following commands to fix windows:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

However, since my PC doesn't recognize any Boot Device, how can I execute Prompt? THis is a OEM Windows, so I don't have a CD. Is there another way, like a live session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Followed [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) to get into Command Prompt and executed both commands:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Windows boot working again.